# ISAPI_rewrite multy string search and rewrite to one

Tags: dns, url-rewriting, isapi-rewrite

I'm new to this, need help writing this rewrite code. I have 7 domains parked on same server and each domain content is in it's own folder currently I'm using like:

> RewriteEngine on
>
> RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R,L]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)?domain1.com$
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)?domain2.com$
>
> RewriteRule (.*) /folder1-2/$1 [NC,L,NS]
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)?domain3.com$
>
> RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www.)?domain4.com$
>
> RewriteRule (.*) /folder3-4/$1 [NC,L,NS]

...and so on -its working, but if some one type like:
domain1.com/folder1-2 -url stays same as is, I like to redirect to folder1-2, but url should only say www.domain1.com (with www prefix and without folder1-2).

can someone please help to write using ISAPI_rewrite.

-thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this for domain 1 and 2:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([^.?]+[^.?/])$ $1/ [R,L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^(?:www\.)?(domain1|domain2)\.com$
RewriteRule ^folder1-2 http://www.%1.com/ [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{HTTP:Host} ^www\.(?:domain1|domain2)\.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ /folder1-2 [NC,L]
```

Comment: I try your code, but it did not work -not sure where is error